# delete or disable "SHOP BY" => Price , Color in magento

Tags: attributes, price

I want to delete or disable "Shop by Color" and "Shop by Price" in magento frontend.

Comment: which extension you are using for this.?

Comment: i'm not using extension. its galagifyshop theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Catalog > Attribute > Manage Attribute and go to the price attribute and color attribute click on both and in frontend properties their is "Use In Layered Navigation" make it as NO. and save

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your reply. it's worked fine....

Answer (score 2):

Go to Catalog->categories->manage categories ->display setting ->Available Product Listing Sort By